# Unable to create connection on MySQL Workbench Edition in Mac?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench on my Mac. I am trying to connect the MySQL. I am not able to connect.

I have attached the screenshot.

I am getting Access denied for user 'root'

[image]

Comment: what version of MySQL? (how You install it) - is it create temp password during installation? could You connect from terminal with command line client and user root?

Comment: I installed workbench and server version. Both are community edition

Comment: I mean - when You install MySQL, it create for You temporary password - did You wrote it? are You use the same or You already change it? Did You try connect to MySQL from terminal window?

Comment: something like - /usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysql --host=127.0.0.1 -u root -p , You can change  5.7.15 - change for You actual version

Comment: Is Workbench on the _same_ computer as mysqld?

Answer (score 1):

Common issues:

- Is MySQL server running? check that by making sure you have 1 or more processes called mysqld
- Is MySQL listening on the 127.0.0.1 address? Make sure it is not running with skip-netwoking or with bind-address different from 0.0.0.0, *, or 127.0.0.1 (it could be only listening on a public ip)
- Is there an user called root? It should be there if you just installed it
- Did you write the right password- in the latest MySQL versions, mysql gets installed with a random default password. You need to know that or connect to the socket (localhost + socket, not 127.0.0.1 + 3306) using the unix_autentication plugin
- What error do you get? It is not the same to get a "could not connect" than a "connection denied"- the first one could be points 1 and 2, the second 3 and 4. Can you connect using the command line "mysql"?
- Do you have the latest mysql workbench version? Latest authentication methids may not be supported on old workbench versions

This is a very common question, please read the manual first for troubleshooting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: thank you .. tutorial you gave me .. very helpful.. now i am getting user root access denied issue..

Comment: A temporary root password must have been created on install: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html use that. If you do not know what that is, either wipe and reinstall, or reset it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html